# Activity - BackgroundTask throwing runtime

Tags: java, android, android-activity, interface, background-task

Before I continue I would like say I have less than 10 hours development time on an android, so please be gentle with your answer.

I thought I had a break through when attempting to get a value back from background task to a tab activity. Read a fair few threads stating the answer lies with a interface / listener, so I thought I have done it right (below) and it throws an runtime.

I will attempt to add comments in the code so you can follow

The Tab activity

```
    public class Tab1Activity extends Activity implements ValueListener 
    {

        String task,username,password;

        @Override
        public void onValueComputed(String computedValue) 
        {
            //do something...
        }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab1);

            BackgroundTask backgroundTaskLogin = new BackgroundTask(Tab1Activity.this);    
            backgroundTaskLogin.execute(task,username,password);
        }
}
```

This is the background Task

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
 {
        Context context;




        BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
        {
            this.context = ctx;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
          // do stuff
          return datastuff    
        }

/////////////////////////////////

 @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            super.onPreExecute();


        }
///////////////////////////////////////


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) 
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }


//////////////////////////////


        ValueListener listener;

        public void MyAsyncTask (ValueListener valueListener) 
        {
            this.listener = valueListener;
        }

        @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(String result)
         {


            listener.onValueComputed(result);

// The value gets here OK - but when adding the above listener it throws a runtime

            System.out.println("kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk"+result);

         }
```

This is the interface

```
public interface ValueListener
{
      public void onValueComputed(String computedValue);

}
```

This is the error

```
01-26 17:26:20.935: E/AndroidRuntime(869): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 17:26:20.935: E/AndroidRuntime(869): Process: com.example.tabdemo, PID: 869
01-26 17:26:20.935: E/AndroidRuntime(869): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.tabdemo.ValueListener.onValueComputed(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
01-26 17:26:20.935: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at com.example.tabdemo.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:223)
01-26 17:26:20.935: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at com.example.tabdemo.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:1)
01-26 17:26:20.935: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
01-26 17:26:20.935: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
01-26 17:26:20.935: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
01-26 17:26:20.935: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-26 17:26:20.935: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
01-26 17:26:20.935: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
01-26 17:26:20.935: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-26 17:26:20.935: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
01-26 17:26:20.935: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Everything is fine until I try and add the listener, is it obvious what the problem is

Comment: Move `BackgroundTask backgroundTaskLogin = new BackgroundTask(Tab1Activity.this);    
        backgroundTaskLogin.execute(task,username,password);` inside of a method. Your `context` is null when it first starts until it's started the lifecycle

Comment: Wait, where is `MyAsyncTask() ` called?

Comment: The background tasks were within a method.. - updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't initialized the `ValueListener` object. I think you have messed up with the constructor logic. This is your constructor :

```
BackgroundTask(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
}
```

There is another method which you may be confusing as your constructor but it isn't.

```
public void MyAsyncTask (ValueListener valueListener) {
            this.listener = valueListener;
        }
```

Now since you never called `MyAsyncTask(ValueListener valueListener)`, your `listener` object reference is null and hence the `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

This is what you should do :

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{        
    private ValueListener listener;

    BackgroundTask(ValueListener listener)
    {
        this.listener= listener;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(String result)
         {


            listener.onValueComputed(result);

// The value gets here OK - but when adding the above listener it throws a runtime

            System.out.println("kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk"+result);

         }
```

You haven't defined **listener** so it's causing NPE on

```
 listener.onValueComputed(result);
```